# How to keep two folders synched?

Tags: windows, directory, sync

I have a dual boot system (Windows + Ubuntu), I would like to keep two folders synchronized from the two different partitions. I searched and found that It can be made using **rsync** or **robocopy**, but I couldn't write a script that works as I expected it to work.

Comment: Have a look at rsyncd - the daemonized version of rsync.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend syncthing.
It allows you to keep 2 folders in sync across 2 or many devices, locally it will use a direct network connection to keep the data in sync.

It also has some awareness when it comes to changes and other smart features.

https://syncthing.net/

This article explains how to setup it up and it's probably the easiest thing you've ever done :)

[Getting started](https://docs.syncthing.net/intro/getting-started.html)

Comment: Maybe you could add examples of how to setup sync for a single folder? I can recommend Syncthing as well..

Comment: I use syncthing to sync files between my windows device and my phone indeed, but how can I sync the two folders locally ?

Comment: Basically when they are on the same network they will use a direct connection, otherwise anonymous relays on the internet are used so that no port forwarding is required.Syncthing does not care where your devices are, from a user perspective it all looks the same.